# asp.net use class object on form

Tags: asp.net, class, properties

I am creating an object at server side of an aspx (test.cs) page from a class  (asp.net 2.0 C#)

```
public partial class Vendor_VendorUsedTicketsPopup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ReportInvoice _objReportInvoice = new ReportInvoice();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _objReportInvoice.ReportId = 1;
    }
}
```

as you see above before Page Load I am creating a new ReportInvoice object and on page load I am setting property ReportId to 1

On test.aspx I want to use the ReportId value bu using the _objReportInvoice object like below

```
<div><% _objReportInvoice.ReportId; %></div>
```

But when I build the site I get the error
*The name '_objReport' does not exist in the current context*

I know that I can create a public integer for ReportId above Page_Load and use it on aspx page. That works fine , but I want to use class object properties on aspx page.

What is the way of doing sth like that ?

Thanks...

Comment: You use "_objReportInvoice" in the code-behind but use "_objReport" in the markup. Either that's a typo in the question or a bug in the code.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake .I have corrected and now I am getting the error below

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a = sign in there to print it to the page:

```
<div><%= _objReportInvoice.ReportId; %></div>
```

However, I would suggest just using a Literal or Label control there and then setting it's text to the ReportID property in the code behind.  Inline code like that can make your HTML messy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works fine now.
Also ReportInvoice object must be declared as public

public ReportInvoice _objReportInvoice = new ReportInvoice();

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your .ASPX markup page inherits from the codebehind class.

This means that unless you declare your field as `protected` or `public`, the .aspx will not have access to your field.

You need to add an access modifier to your field to make it non-private.